# Javascript regex match() returning part (subset) of match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this JavaScript regex:

`var e = new RegExp('(, )?wortel')`

So my goal is to match either `"wortel"` OR `", wortel"`, thus putting the ", " encapsulated in brackets and using a question mark to indicate one or zero occurences.


But when I execute this line of code:

```
'pus, wortel'.match(e)
```

I get this output:

```
Array [ ", wortel", ", " ]
```

Why is the second result(`", "`) being included in the matches? Does my regex not require the word "wortel" ? And how do I achieve my desired regex specifications?

PS I am used to Ruby regex, so explaining the difference might help

Comment: It's expected behavior when `g` flag is not specified. The first element is the whole regex, the 2nd element is the text captured by capturing group.

Comment: Please note that this will also match `notawortel` and `wortelvegetable`.

Comment: so it would be `var e = new RegExp("(, )?\\bwortel\\b", "g")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because of the optional capturing group in your regex:

```
var e = new RegExp('(, )?wortel');
```

You can avoid capturing `", "` by using a non capturing group with `(?:...)` syntax:

```
var e = new RegExp('(?:, )?wortel');
```

Here `(?:, )?` makes it **non capturing** group.

Now result will be just one element:

```
Array [ ", wortel" ]
```

Comment: Yes agreed Javascript certainly behaves differently with `g` flag but I don't remember seeing this global flag behavior in other languages.

Comment: In C# for example  it is implemented as `Regex.Matches` (plural)

Comment: @anubhava: The standard probably want to keep the return value in a non-nested array, so they design the `match` function to return only the main matches in the `g` flag and return the main match + capturing groups when `g` flag is not specified.

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh, yes I think avoiding non-nested is the main reason why it is implemented this way in JS.